bash: "no such file or directory" for executable in PATH
In my process of installing java (as part of weblogic) with ansible I get this issue. I have seen that before from time to time, but cannot recall the solution.
I have a new linux user "weblogic" in group "weblogic" on a ubuntu24, HOME=/opt/oracle
I ssh to that remote machine as my own user, then I do sudo su weblogic. I export JAVA_HOME and PATH, either via .bashrc or manually
declare -x PATH="/opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431"

But when I do either/or
java
bash: /opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin/java: No such file or directory

/opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin/java
bash: /opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin/java: No such file or directory

Permissions are like that, all the way down from /opt
drwxr-xr-x  4 weblogic weblogic  4096 Dez  9 15:27 oracle/

Originally I assumed it is an issue with ansible i am not aware of and asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79265126/using-the-lookup-ansible-builitin-env-on-the-environment-variable-path-does-not

(1) /opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin/java is an absolute path, so the shell does not use $PATH to "resolve" it. (2) What is the output of file /opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin/java? (3) This maybe?

thanks for the hint.  I tried to run i586 java on x64 . Do you want to add solution? Otherwise I add myself and add that link to the other question

My knowledge in this topic comes from the link. After reading that answer you know the theory as much as I do; but now you also have practical experience, I do not. So I'm not going to write an answer, go ahead. Two things: (1) There is no need to mention me in your answer, keep it technical. (2) (You probably know this.) The answer should be more than just the link; it may be basic and quite terse, yet it should be standalone. IMO "I tried to run i586 java on x64" plus the most relevant part (quote) from the linked answer will do.

What does ls -l, file, and head -1 on /opt/oracle/jdk1.8.0_431/bin/java give you?
